# Algebra word structure question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If five times a number is added to three times the number, the result is the sum of seven times the number and $9$. Find the number.

I am pretty sure it is $5x+3x=7x+9$ although I am not positive.

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. Solve for $x$ and get $8x-7x=x=9$.

Hope that helps!